# Invalid 'departure_time' parameter when using Google distance matrix api

Tags: python, google-distancematrix-api

I want to calculate the drive time using the `distance matrix API` - while doing so I need to calculate the drive time at specific times of the day and therefore I'm using the `departure_time` parameter. However, I can't seem to figure out the correct format that I need to specify the time in. When I set `departure_time=now` in the API URL works fine. But when I try to specify a time, say 1pm, I get an error `Invalid request. Invalid departure_time parameter.`

For example, the following URL works fine (API key removed) - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=53.542416,-1.437382&destinations=54.552902,-6.000198999999999&key=XXXX&mode=driving&departure_time=now

But this one doesn't - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=53.542416,-1.437382&destinations=54.552902,-6.000198999999999&key=XXXX&mode=driving&departure_time=2021-09-21T13:00:00.00000Z

Can someone please advise on what's the best way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameters `arrival_time` and `departure_time` should be given as a **`timestamp`**, seconds after `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

E.g. in `python` this is done by calling `date.timestamp()` on a `datetime`-object.

Answer (score 0):

The departure time should be a timestamp expressed in seconds. in Javascript, something like `let newDate = new
Date(currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay,prevHour,prevMinutes);

let timeinSeconds = newDate.getTime()/1000;`
Will give the departure time expressed as a timestamp in seconds then can be supplied in place of "now"